# Application Not Getting Loaded in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

My application is almost complete and I needed to change the package names. So I refactored the names and after I renamed the package that contained the MAIN class, this warning is getting displayed - " **No definition found for exported static routine: .main(String[])**".

On googling, I found that this is because compiler didn't find any entry points for the application and that's why the application is not getting loaded in to the simulator/device.

Can anybody please help me on this ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

As the error message implies, you must have a method with the signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

defined in one of your classes. It doesn't matter which but it is common to define it in the class that extends Application or UiApplication since this method creates the Application or UiApplication object and enters the event dispatcher. You must have had such a method at some point if you ever ran the application on the simulator or device.

Comment: I do have this main method defined in the class. Still it's throwing this warning and the app is not getting loaded.

Comment: After I changed the package names, I got this warning - No definition found for exported static routine: .main(String[]). With this warning in place, the application was getting packaged successfully, but was not getting loaded.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code for your definition of the method.

Comment: The main method definition is same and it's working fine with package name starting with com. The only change I made is changing it to org and the application stopped getting loaded into the device/simulator.

public static void main(String args[]) {

  APPNAME theApp = new APPNAME ();
  theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
 }